# ubuntu style change workspace in osx mavericks

Tags: macos, spaces

is there any way to make osx (mavericks) change the between workspaces like ubuntu > 12.0

i mean the 4 window workspaces and switching by going up/down/right/left

the current change workspace in osx is only left/right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was actually a feature in Mac OS X Leopard (v10.5) and Snow Leopard (v10.6), but was changed in Lion. The general Mac term is “spaces”.

[TotalSpaces2](http://totalspaces.binaryage.com) brings back a grid setup, like in Ubuntu and the older versions of OS X.

Comment: its not free ... any alternate?